# How I can detect if an object is removed by the Garbage Collector?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, garbage-collection

I need a way to detect when an object is disposed by GC on Javascript especifically V8 engine (I need to implement something with that workining on google chrome and node)

Answer (score 2):

You can't from within a program unless maybe via some kind of debugging hooks.

The EcmaScript committee explicitly rejected [a proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman%3aweak_references) in part because it exposed such a thing indirectly:

> Note that `makeWeakRef` is not safe for general access since it grants access to the non-determinism inherent in observing garbage collection. The resulting side channel reveals information that may violate the confidentiality assumptions of other programs.

In other words, being able to tell when an object is garbage collected could allow JavaScript to collect information about other code in violation of the same-origin policy.

---

From V8's embedding API, you can get notified about certain objets though via a [`makeWeak` callback](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1Persistent.html#ab04609812113450bece2640ad0b27658):

> When only weak handles refer to the object, the garbage collector will perform a callback to the given `V8::WeakReferenceCallback` function, passing it the object reference and the given parameters.